# Display existing list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, web-part

Any suggestions how to display existing list in chart, or graph. Chart Web part is deprecated for 2013.

Also 3rd parties aren't an option?

Comment: Yes chart web part is not present in web part gallery in SharePoint 2013. There is a work around for this :  Export the `.webpart` file from the web part galley in SharePoint 2010 and upload it to your site collection web part gallery in SharePoint 2013. And after that you can use chart web part in SharePoint 2013 as well.

Comment: I tried to upload the .webpart  to SP2013 , I got error . I have full permission to do that . Do you have any idea ?

Comment: refer this link - Refer this link - http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/06/how-to-enable-chart-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Appreciated all . I did it

Answer (score 2):

Use jqplot for the same. You can get from Google.

Comment: its a jq . Right ?

Comment: Yes, it is jQuery.

Comment: Could you clarify a little more please? Thanks

Comment: I will get code and post here by tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSOM to read the data from lists and [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to create the graphs.

Sample: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-a-chart-using-chartjs-in-sharepoint-server-2013

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) and use CEWP to reference the js file(s).  More details [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-a-chart-using-chartjs-in-sharepoint-server-2013)